# How to connect to mdf of local database , which is giving "sql network interfaces error 52"

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

I have started a new project which i will be displaying the data in the grid view, where i have to consume the .mdf file. Here the problem starts. I am able to open the .mdf file in sql data base, but not by selecting as servertype: "database engine" but by selecting "SQL server compact edition", only then i am able to open the .mdf file in sql studio and create the tables and everything.

I have creted tables and everthing, and now comes the part where i have to give the connection string in the web.config file. I have defined as below.

connstring:

```
     connectionString="Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\Users\usr\Downloads\InterviewSolution\Backup\myproject\App_Data\myproject.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and i am not able to connect. I have tried to test the connection while configuring the database schema to sqldatasource, but it is failing with below error.

error: "sql network interfaces error 52"

I thought it was permissions issue, and gave full permissions to the file by adding NFS account to it. but still the same, not able to connect through project.

Can anyone pls help me on this, why is the file able to connect to sql studio, but was not able to connect  through project.

Is my connection string wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

I always use this template for this case of connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>     
    <add name="MyConn" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myproject.mdf;
         Integrated Security=True;
         User Instance=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>     
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: hello jpgrassi, i have even tried that. but getting same error.

Comment: When i try to connect through server explorer in visual studio, i am getting,"sql network error-26, srver could not be found" . is there any setting i need to be done, i could'nt figure out whats the issue is. its bugging me

Comment: Have you tried searching for this error? It is related to the SQl Instnace.. something is wrong in your configs..